# Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming using Opti Toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: mathematical-optimization, quadprog

I wish to solve a mixed integer quadratic program with linear constraints using OPTI toolbox in MATLAB. I want some of my decision variables to be continuous and some decision variables to be binary. How do I specify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want some of my decision variables to be continuous and some
>   decision variables to be binary. How do I specify this?

The way to specify which variables are of which type is shown at the [bottom of this page](http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/index.php/Probs/MILP).

Quoting:

> **Example 5: Specifying Long Integer Variable Strings**
>
> A common question we get is how to specify xtype when you have lots of
>   integer variables. Assuming your variables are ordered (i.e.
>   continuous, integer and binary variables are in consecutive groups),
>   the following example shows a shorthand trick to enter them.
>
> ```
> % Objective
> nC = 10; %Number of Continuous Variables
> nI = 10; %Number of Integer Variables
> nB = 10; %Number of Binary Variables
>
> % Build xtype vector
> xtype = [repmat('C',1,nC),repmat('I',1,nI),repmat('B',1,nB)]
> ```

So `xtype` is a vector with as many components as variables, and each component defines the type of each variable, which can be

- Continuous (`'C'`)
- Integer (`'I'`)
- Binary (`'B'`)

After specifying `xtype`, you need to pass it to the OPTI object as shown in [this example](http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/index.php/Probs/MIQP):

> ```
> % Objective
> H = [1 -1; -1  2];          %Objective Function (min 0.5x'Hx + f'x)
> f = -[2 6]';                
>
> % Constraints
> A = [1,1; -1,2; 2, 1];      %Linear Inequality Constraints (Ax <= b)
> b = [2;2;3];    
> lb = [0;0];                 %Bounds on x (lb <= x)
>
> % Integer Constraints - We do it as above (using repmat) in your case
> xtype = 'IC';
>
> % Create OPTI Object
> Opt = opti('qp',H,f,'ineq',A,b,'lb',lb,'xtype',xtype)
>
> % Solve the MIQP problem
> [x,fval,exitflag,info] = solve(Opt)
> ```

I hope this helps!